# APK not running on real device - Manifest error?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new on app's code. My project runs perfectly on emulators. However the apk is not running in my samsung device. Checking it with the Android Studio Analyzer the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the manifest.xml returns in red. It seems that something is wrong with my project Manifest. Any Help? My manifest is copied below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
package="com.ferleecidade.a100dia11">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<application
    android:theme="@ref/0x7f0f0005"
    android:label="@ref/0x7f0e001f"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f0c0000"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f0c0002">

    <activity
        android:name="com.ferleecidade.a100dia11.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.ferleecidade.a100dia11.MyCustomList" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@ref/0x7f020003" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What error do you get while running app on device?

Answer (score 0):

Help? Yes.
I am actively looking into this right now.
I don't believe your manifest is causing this or at least isn't the sole cause. 
I have a project that I can run on my devices and emulators and deploy without a glitch.
I also get an error on the same line you do when analyzing the APK (Build/.Analyze APK).
If you hover your cursor over the red text you will see your error popup.

Mine says "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages and Frameworks | Schemes and DTDs)"

I performed a quick experiment.

1. created a brand new project in Android Studio with a single activity.
2. Cleaned the project.
3. Ran in an emulator.
4. Generated a signed APK.
5. Analyzed the APK and the error is there.

I suggest you try this.

This leads me to believe one of two things.

1. There is something wrong with my default project settings.
2. The error is being incorrectly reported by Android studio.

I hope this was useful.